# Given a list of integers , return 3 if there is a 3 next to a 3 somewhere

Tags: python

> Given a list of ints ,return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere .

My code returns true if there is a 3 at the first index (followed by a 3) but returns a false if 3 at any other index(followed by a 3).

What am i doing wrong?

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for i in args:
        for x in range(len(args)): 
            if i[x]==i[x+1] and i[x]==3:
                return True
            else:
                pass
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops here?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], it's unclear how you expect your function to be called (and if you expect it to accept a single list, don't use the `*args` syntax, use a simple variable.

Comment: "return True" will exit the function and won't check for any further 3

Comment: @Domino This is what the function is supposed to do in this case.

Comment: The outer loop `for i in args:` is unnecessary and meaningless, consider that `i[x]` and `i[x+1]` won't mean anything. Solution: simply refer to `args[x]` instead of `i[x]`. (Or you could assign `i = args` if you wanted to refer to them as `i[...]`. But don't do that; in Python i,k etc. usually mean simple integer indices, but here you called it `x`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just one line:

```
def myfunc(*args): return any([3, 3] == list(args[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(args)))
```

You pratcally check if there are two consecutive `3` (represented by the list `[3, 3]`) in any consecutive subset of the input (represented by the slice `args[i:i+2]`)

Comment: I think you should subtract something from `len(args)`, otherwise, the slice goes out the back

Comment: There is no needing since at most you will produce a slice of length 0 or 1, so the condition `[3, 3] == [x]` or `[3, 3] == []` never yields `True`

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip to access items along with their successors:

```
def dup3s(*args):
    return (3,3) in zip(args,args[1:])
```